# Collect links from div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this part in code for collecting links:

```
def Get_Links():
r = requests.get(main).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
links = []
for item in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'ap-area-link'}):
    links.append(item.get("href"))
return links
```

This works if web page source is:

```
<a class="ap-area-link" href="https://www.webpage.com/product/item/">Item</a>
```

What if web page source code is:

```
<div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
     <h5 class="show-for-small">Product Name</h5>
      <a href="https://webpage.com/products/item/">Item</a>
    </div>
```

I have tried:

```
def Get_Links():
    r = requests.get(main).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    links = []
    for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'large-4 medium-4 columns'}):
        links.append(item.get("href"))
    return links
```

But my list of links is empty then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try some like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
     <h5 class="show-for-small">Product Name 1</h5>
      <a href="https://webpage.com/products/item/">Item</a>
      <h5 class="show-for-small">Product Name 2</h5>
      <a href="https://webpage.com/products/item/">Item</a>
    </div>
       """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'large-4 medium-4 columns'}):
  for n in item.find_all('a'): 
    print ('Link : '+ n.get('href'))
```

Result :

```
Link : https://webpage.com/products/item/
Link : https://webpage.com/products/item/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` method on the **item**. The `find_all` method returns a set of answers, kind of like an array. This way you can just use a regular bs4 method on each item of the result set. You can treat the items in the result-set as individual html-content.

#### Try replacing:

`for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'large-4 medium-4 columns'}):
     links.append(item.get("href"))`

#### With:

`for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'large-4 medium-4'}): 
     links.append(item.find("a"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using an adjacent sibling combinator to get the `a` after the `h5` with the class shown below

```
links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('h5.show-for-small + a')]
```

Read about css selectors and combinators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).